# Adding (existing data) to Array in Formik

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, formik

this is my component:

```
import { Field, FieldArray, Form, Formik } from "formik";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import { updateEpisode } from "../../ducks/episodes/actions";
const AddActorToMovie = (
  { history, updateEpisode, episode, characters },
  props
) => {
  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    updateEpisode(values);
    history.push("/episodes");
  };
  console.log("halo", episode);
  return (
    <div>
      {episode ? (
        <div>
          <h3>Add Main Character to episode</h3>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{
              id: episode.id,
              title: episode.title,
              release_date: episode.release_date,
              series: episode.series,
              img: episode.img,
              charactersList: episode.charactersList, // this would be an array
            }}
            onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
            enableReinitialize={true}
          >
            <Form>
              <Field name="charactersList" as="select">
                <option value=""> Brak informacji </option>
                {characters.map((char) => (
                  <option
                    key={char.id}
                    value={char.id}
                  >{`${char.name}`}</option>
                ))}
              </Field>
              <button type="submit">Zatwierdz</button>
            </Form>
          </Formik>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    episode: state.episodes.episodes
      ? state.episodes.episodes.find(
          (x) => String(x.id) === props.match.params.id
        )
      : null,
    characters: state.characters.characters,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  updateEpisode,
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddActorToMovie)
);
```

What i would like to do, is instead of adding only one `value = char.id` to `charactersList` i woudl like to add multiple. So that `charactersList` woudl be an array and i could add as many `characters` i could and also if possible i could also `delete` some of them in this form, as im using my `updateEpisode` action so that im passing a updated object to my state.
I know that probably i shoudl do it with `FieldArray` but i don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Personally i don't use `<Field />`, i prefer manual `setFieldValue` because it gives you more freedom. By using `setFieldValue` you can loop through the **char.id** and push them to the charactersList by getting prev value from 'value.charactersList' and set the new value with `setFieldValue`.

```js
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    id: episode.id,
    title: episode.title,
    release_date: episode.release_date,
    series: episode.series,
    img: episode.img,
    charactersList: episode.charactersList, // this would be an array
  }}
  onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
  enableReinitialize={true}
>
  {
    ({ values, setFieldValue, handleSubmit }) => (
      <Form>
        <h3>Character List</h3>
        {
          characters.map((char) => (
            <button name={char.id} value={char.id} onclick={() => {
              const oldData = values.charactersList;
              if(!Array.isArray(oldData)) return;
              const isExist = oldData?.includes(char.id)
              if(isExist) {
                // filter out the char u want to delete
                const newData = oldData?.filter(i => i !== char.id)
                setFieldValue('characterList', newData)
                return;
              }
              const newData = oldData?.concat(char.id);
              setFieldValue('characterList', newData);
            }}>
              {char.name}
            </button>
          ))
        }
        
        <button type="submit" onclick={handleSubmit}>Zatwierdz</button>
      </Form>
    )
  }
</Formik>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/formik/dist/formik.umd.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok, it did work. But do you know how i can manage it so you could not add character of same id twice?

Comment: i've updated code above, adding `isExist`

Comment: Thanks! But know i also wonder, how can i implement deleting? Is it possible to delete data using this form? Let's just say that if this character already exsist in array, i can click the button or any other button to remove him from the charactersList

Comment: you can filter out the when button with the same char id clicked, then feed back the data to the values using `setFieldValues` just like my last edit